# Posting is 'None' for some members of Google Group

Tags: google, forum

For some reason the "Posting" column is set to "None" for some members of my Google Group despite having been set to "Default group policy" as with all other members. I even selected "Override - Allow posting" for these members which made absolutely no difference.

Is there a way to fix this?